# AWS Serverless - adding response headers

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

I’m following the documentation in order to set response headers. I’m doing so because CORS is not letting me do anything.

Anyways, the docs (https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/#responses) says I can do it like this:

```
events:
  - http:
      method: get
      path: whatever
      response:
        headers:
          Content-Type: "'text/html'"
```

However, it seems like the docs aren’t up to date because serverless is complaining when deploying, `Serverless: Configuration warning at 'functions.myFunction.events[1].httpApi': unrecognized property 'response'`

How do you set response headers in the newest version?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That error appears to be coming from an `httpApi` event, not the `http` event you included in your question.  Do you perhaps have another event with the type `httpApi` elsewhere in your `serverless.yaml`?  If so, it will break if you include a `response` in it because it uses a different schema than the regular `http` event type.

Docs on `httpApi` events: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/http-api/

Docs on `http` events: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/